# Change boolean value in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, boolean, modelform

I have field in my Model which indicates whether a user wants to receive emails

```
receive_invites = models.BooleanField(default=True, help_text="Receive an invite email from friends")
```

I also have a view with an option:

> [ x ] I do not want to receive emails...

By **default** receive_invites is **True** therefore the checkbox is **ticked**. However, I'd like the user to tick the checkbox  in order to change receive_invites to **False**. I did the following in my ModelForm to achieve this. Does anybody have a more elegant way of doing this?

```
class UnsubscribeForm(forms.ModelForm):        
    class Meta:
        model = Entrant
        fields = ('receive_invites')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            instance = kwargs['instance']
            if instance.receive_invites:
                instance.receive_invites = False
            else:
                instance.receive_invites = True
        super(UnsubscribeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and in the view I have this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    unsubscribe_form = UnsubscribeForm(request.POST, instance=me)

    if unsubscribe_form.is_valid():
        receive_invites = unsubscribe_form.cleaned_data['receive_invites']
        if receive_invites:
            user.receive_invites = False
        else:
            user.receive_invites = True
        unsubscribe_form.save()
        return redirect('index')
else:
    unsubscribe_form = UnsubscribeForm(instance=me)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on to @DrTyrsa, it's unreasonable to go through so much convolution just to follow a field naming convention. If you're attached to that field name, you can always add a property to the model that maps the data field to a value you care about:

```
dont_receive_invites = models.BooleanField(default=False, help_text="Don't receive an invite email from friends")

@property
def receive_invites(self):
    return not self.dont_receive_invites
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't alter the model? If you can, create `dont_receive_invites` field instead and save a lot of time.

Comment: the whole point is not to change the field name, I have other fields that have the same naming convention (trying to be consistent)

Comment: @NgoMinhNam What's the point of naming convention if it creates these problems? The final goal is to make code readable, not complicate it because of some conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just remove the words "do not" from the view?

> [ x ] I want to receive emails...

Otherwise, I'd recommend changing `UnsubscribeForm` from a `ModelForm` to a plain `Form`. Then you can invert booleans all you want without resorting to trickery. It's more work, but it'll work if you can't just change the label.

Comment: I can't change the words and that's a bad UX btw. I don't want to use Form because I need to use other fields in the model as well and only this one needs to be changed.